# Java Google SpreadSheet API, how to update cell to add a note?

Tags: java, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

Well, I need to find a way to add a note in a google spreadsheet, I'm using java to connect.

I Have built a request that changes cell colours, but I can't find a way to update cell to add a note.

This is how I change build request to change the colour:

```
    private Request buildRequestToPaintCell(int startRow, int endRow, int startColumn, int endColumn, int sheetId) {
    Request request = new Request();
    request.setRepeatCell(new RepeatCellRequest()
            .setCell(new CellData()
                    .setUserEnteredFormat(new CellFormat().setBackgroundColor(new Color()
                            .setRed(1f)
                            .setGreen(0.0f)
                            .setBlue(0.0f))))
            .setRange(new GridRange()
                    .setSheetId(sheetId)
                    .setStartRowIndex(startRow)
                    .setEndRowIndex(endRow)
                    .setStartColumnIndex(startColumn)
                    .setEndColumnIndex(endColumn))
            .setFields("userEnteredFormat.backgroundColor")
            );
    return request;
}
```

I was expecting this to work, but it doesn't as I set the field as '*' it clears the cell and adds the note, but that's not what I need, I think I'm missing the correct field value to update just the note, I can not find it yet.

```
private Request buildRequestAddNoteCell(int startRow, int endRow, int startColumn, int endColumn, int sheetId, String note) {
    Request request = new Request();
    request.setRepeatCell(new RepeatCellRequest()
            .setCell(new CellData().setNote(note))
            .setRange(new GridRange()
                    .setSheetId(sheetId)
                    .setStartRowIndex(startRow)
                    .setEndRowIndex(endRow)
                    .setStartColumnIndex(startColumn)
                    .setEndColumnIndex(endColumn))
            .setFields("userEnteredFormat.note")
            );
    return request;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found it. Had to set the fields as 'note'. It is missing doc about the cell fields.

Example code:

```
private Request buildRequestAddNoteCell(int startRow, int endRow, int startColumn, int endColumn, int sheetId, String note) {
    Request request = new Request();
    request.setRepeatCell(new RepeatCellRequest()
            .setCell(new CellData().setNote(note))
            .setRange(new GridRange()
                    .setSheetId(sheetId)
                    .setStartRowIndex(startRow)
                    .setEndRowIndex(endRow)
                    .setStartColumnIndex(startColumn)
                    .setEndColumnIndex(endColumn))
            .setFields("note")
            );
    return request;
}
```