# How can I insert a comment with the Sheets API?

Tags: java, google-sheets, httprequest, google-sheets-api

I am using the [Google Sheets API](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/) to to read spreadsheets and operate on the data. My application has limited permissions on the sheet it's operating on. I can not edit cell values, only add comments.

I want to use my application to write comments on specific cells (e.g `M64` or `A1`), but I cannot figure out how to do it. I saw [Insert a comment in a Google Sheet with google-sheets-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50564368/insert-a-comment-in-a-google-sheet-with-google-sheets-api), but this thread does not present a way to insert comments with Java.

I attempted the following, which I found on [Java Google SpreadSheet API, how to update cell to add a note?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53176460/java-google-spreadsheet-api-how-to-update-cell-to-add-a-note). It executed with no errors, but the cell never obtained a comment:

```
Request request = new Request();
request.setRepeatCell(
        new RepeatCellRequest()
        .setCell(
                new CellData()
                .setNote("test"))
        .setRange(
                new GridRange()
                .setSheetId(1)  // Sheet 1
                .setStartRowIndex(0)
                .setEndRowIndex(13)     //
                .setStartColumnIndex(0) // Cell M64
                .setEndColumnIndex(64)  //
        )
        .setFields("note")
        );
BatchUpdateSpreadsheetRequest batch = new BatchUpdateSpreadsheetRequest();
batch.setRequests(Arrays.asList(new Request[] {request}));
service.spreadsheets().batchUpdate(spreadsheetId, batch);
```

Does anyone know how to use the Google API Client Library for Java and the Sheets API to add a comment to a spreadsheet?

Comment: Although I'm not sure about the whole script, how about modifying from ``service.spreadsheets().batchUpdate(spreadsheetId, batch)`` to ``service.spreadsheets().batchUpdate(spreadsheetId, batch).execute()``? [Ref](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/batchupdate?hl=en) If this was not the direct solution, I apologize.

Comment: @Tanaike that actually got me somewhere! Now I am having trouble with authentication though...

Comment: Thank you for replying. I apologize that my proposal was not the direct solution of your issue.